# Comparing the 1st element of list of lists to another list then adding only the lists that match to a new list

Tags: python, list, sorting, list-comprehension

My aim is to compare the 1st element of a list of lists with another list and have the lists added to a new list if the 1st elements of both lists match. So for instance,

```
list1 = [2,4,7,10]
list2 = [[2,5],[3,7],[1,6],[10,3]]

newlist = [[2,5],[10,3]]
```

Comment: The list1 is always expected to be some correlation with list2?  What if list1 is ```[2, 7, 10, 4]```

Answer (score 2):

What if the list1 items does NOT have exactly sequence matching list2?

Let's assume list1 has [2, 7, 10, 4], and list2 is the same as posted sample.
Using pure **zip** won't get what you expect!

Alternatively, you could try this approach: (it works **w/o assuming** there is a matching ordering relationship between the two lists)

```
L = [2, 7, 4, 10]
M = [[10, 1], [3, 5], [2, 8], [4, 6], [10, 10]]

result = []

for ll in M:
    if ll[0] in set(L):
        result.append(ll)
result.append(ll)

print(result)
# [[10, 1], [2, 8], [4, 6], [10, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()`:

```
newlist = []

for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    if a == b[1]:
        newlist.append(b)
```

Or with a generator expression:

```
newlist = [b for a, b in zip(list1, list2) if a == b[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list comprehension:

```py
[snd for fst, snd in zip(list1, list2) if fst == snd[0]]
```

This outputs:

```py
[[2, 5], [10, 3]]
```